# Stellar HD Path require apostrophe in the end?

Tags: stellar-core, paths

I was recently going through some code and came across something new to me.

The HD Paths for all the assets I saw ended with `/0` but specifically for Stellar it ended with `/0'`.

The complete form: `m/44'/148'/0'/0'`.

Is there a specific reason for this? If I omit the apostrophe in the end will it have any effect on anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivation path for stellar is defined in [SEP-5](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/ecosystem/sep-0005.md) and only uses the first three levels. The default path is `m/44'/148'/0'`

The fourth level would have been a flag for [change addresses](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki#change), which doesn't apply to stellar. The apostrophe indicates the usage of *hardened addresses* which doesn't apply to  `change` at all, so it must not be at the 4th level even if it would somehow apply to stellar.

I suppose any wallet using more levels will either ignore any but the first three levels or generate non standardized addresses.